# Can I still retrieve tweets using the free developer tier in Python?

Tags: twitter, permissions, tweepy, tiers

New to X and watching some videos I saw that you could retrieve tweets in Python but reading the docs I am wondering if I am still allowed to do that or must I go the $100/m basic level? I only want to play with it and maybe I’m doing something silly. Any advice, hugely appreciated.

I get an error that many have talked about but as I can see not recently. I am wondering if things have changed. I can connect and auth but I get the error:

> Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
> 453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level.

I was hoping that some of the old YouTube videos are still relevant but after the rebranding, etc. I wonder if I am barking up the wrong tree and just need to pay to get such access these days.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!

The error message here is telling you exactly what the problem is

If you want to access this, you'll need to increase your access level (presumably by paying)

Comment: Before requires StackOverflow contribution, understand how API works, and all security requirement layers to have it integrated with your solution

Answer (score 0):

Reading tweets via API is no longer free. You're not supposed to, but you could parse HTML from a local nitter instance, use selenium (may be detected easily), or use a redis + native messaging host + browser extension combo.

Comment: Thankyou, sincerely appreciated.